# Root Square Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Prove that if $A_n\geq 0$, $A_n\rightarrow A$ in norm, then $\sqrt{A_n}\rightarrow\sqrt{A}$ in norm.

Where everything are bounded and linear operators in a Hilbert space. I did this

$$\|\sqrt{A_n}-\sqrt{A}\|\leq\|\sqrt{A_n}-A_n\|+\|A_n-A\|+\|A-\sqrt{A}\|$$

then it's sufficient to prove that  $\|\sqrt{A_n}-A_n\|$ is small enough, but is this true? can you get that norm difference as small as you wish?

I though, may be using Hilbert- Schmidt theorem since $\sqrt{A_n}$ is self-adjoint.

so, if $A_nx=\sum\lambda_i(\phi_i,x)\phi_i$, with $\lambda_i$ singular values such that $\lambda_i\rightarrow0$ and $\{\phi_i\}$ orthonormal basis, then
$$\|\sqrt{A_n}-A_n\|=\|\sum\lambda_i(\phi_i,x)\phi_i-\sum\lambda_i^2(\phi_i,x)\phi_i\|\leq\|\sum\lambda_i-\lambda_i^2\|\leq\sum\|\lambda_i-\lambda_i^2\|$$
but, since $\lambda_i\rightarrow 0$, $\|\lambda_i-\lambda_i^2\|\rightarrow 0$, it's all this true?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $A_n$? Are they normal? positive definite?

Comment: Just positive, bounded and linear.

Comment: see this it think it will be useful http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24392/simple-inequality-in-c-algebras

Comment: and this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252004/if-a-n-is-a-sequence-of-positive-bounded-linear-operators-converging-in-norm-t?rq=1

Comment: thanks, let me take a look!

Comment: What do you mean by "positive"? what is the definition of a "positive" operator?

Comment: A is positive if and only if for all $x$ in the space, $(Ax,x)\geq0$.

Comment: Your last argument--if true--would imply that $\sqrt{A_n}-A_n\rightarrow 0$. Do you believe that would be true?

Comment: Not really, I don't think that happen.. I'm asking too much.